# Why all the arraylist stored in the database?

Tags: android, arraylist, spinner

The issue was, the data for tuitionPackage did not appear/save in the firebase database. The tuition package data is in the spinner type.

Here's my code:

```java
ArrayList<TuitionPackage> tuitionPackages = new ArrayList<>();
        tuitionPackages.add(new TuitionPackage());
        tuitionPackages.addAll(mAdvertisement.getTuitionPackages());

        StudentRegistration studentRegistration = new StudentRegistration(uid, tuitioname, fullname, icnum, homeaddress, parentname, parentcontactnum, userUid, tuitionPackages);
        mDatabase.child("Student Registration").child(uid).setValue(studentRegistration).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
            {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Successfully registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, FinishActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }

                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                loadingBar.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

[image: Screenshot of Firebase Realtime Database]

Comment: Please consider cropping your screenshot so that users can save their data from loading the image. (EDIT: I've helped you crop it, but please consider doing so in the future)

Comment: @Edric Okay sir noted. Do you have any idea on my issue?